# The differences between Qdrant upload_records and upsert methods?

Tags: large-language-model, vector-database, semantic-search, qdrant, qdrantclient

I am new to the Qdrant vector database and its literature. As I understand, for uploading data to the Qdrant client database, we use uploading methods such as `upsert` and `upload_records` but I did not get when should use each one.

Can anyone clarify the usage and any other recommendations about them?

Answer (score 0):

This is specific to the Qdrant Python client, other clients don't have the `upload_records` function.

`upsert()` matches the point upsertion endpoint in the Qdrant API<sup>1</sup>. It allows you to upload a batch of points, like other clients.

`upload_records()` is a helper function with a similar purpose. Instead of giving it a batch of points, you can provide any `Iterable` holding `Record`s. It is easier to work with and automatically takes care of batching for you.

[image]
Source: https://python-client.qdrant.tech/qdrant_client.client_base.html?highlight=upload_records#qdrant_client.client_base.QdrantBase.upload_records

---

<sup>1</sup> https://qdrant.tech/documentation/concepts/points/#upload-points